# How would I prevent parts of my player model from displaying on the camera?

Tags: unity, c#, first-person-shooter

The "legs" of my playermodel are shown when looking down. I'm using the Unity First Person Controller template.

Character when in Scene view:

[image: Character in Scene view]

Character when looking down in Play mode:

[image: Character in Play mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Layers to control what's visible to each camera.

First, create a layer for "FirstPersonHidden" objects, [following the instructions in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html).

For each object you want to hide, set its layer to this one using the **Layer** drop-down menu at the top-right of the Inspector.

Then, on your camera, open up the **Culling Mask** drop-down and ensure this layer is unchecked.

Now the marked objects will be hidden from your camera's view.